# how to define the corrected feature extent after using conversion tools in arcgis 10.2?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, extents

I have a map in dgn format. After using conversion tools in arcgis to extract river layer, the feature extent as followed

[image: the feature extent after conversion]

and the project is unknown. I can define the project using define project in arctool box, however, the feature extent is weird, I want to change to the corrected one.
the corrected extent should be[image: the corrected extent should be]

How do I redefine the feature extent of that map?

Comment: Is the unit not meters? Or was there a scaling in the original DGN?